# Stack Exchange flair broken from Stack Exchange (and other sites)

Tags: bug, flair, combined-flair

See:

> [image]

The broken image links to:

https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/218674.png which redirects you to https://stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/users/flair/218674.png

Here is the header information:

> [image]

and a curl request:

```
Nathans-iMac:~ nathan$ curl https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/218674.png
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/error?aspxerrorpath=/users/flair/218674.png">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
Nathans-iMac:~ nathan$
```

**Update**

Both me and @MartijnPieters have tried from various locations and it seems to be a hit and miss thing. From my location I get redirected, but from my personal VM the image downloads correctly.

Comment: [No repro](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LVLCU.png)

Comment: @hims056 That's strange. Does http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/218674.png load correctly?

Comment: Yes I can see it!

Comment: if I load it through https it loads correctly, otherwise redirects me to the 404

Comment: Loads correctly for me; the `/error?aspxerrorpath=` entry there points to a temporary failure. Try a force reload / cache clear.

Comment: cleared my cache, tried in a browser that I haven't used in ages. Strange problem..

Comment: @Prisoner: have you tried using the incognito (private) browser mode (Chrome or Firefox) to look at that URL while not logged in?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I tried with the incognito mode in Google Chrome, but that flair link gives me an error message (the one with the panda).

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Nope, still works fine for me, incognito or otherwise, with or without a cache clean. IP address for `stackexchange.com` is `69.59.197.21` according to my DNS. Perhaps yours is different and we are looking at different servers?

Comment: @MartijnPieters That is the same IP I get from pinging stackexchange.com.

Comment: same IP for me as well when pinging SE..

Comment: Tested with `wget http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/218674.png` as well, works too. Ah, but on my home server this fails! Suddenly, the customer network here is suspicious...

Comment: @MartijnPieters http://pastebin.com/PEwhiQCG thats what I get

Comment: Yet on the 3G network on my phone it works. Yay for either network-wide caches or intermittent failures!

Comment: More data points: different servers located in different networks either consistently get the error, or consistently load the image.

Comment: @MartijnPieters can you try again, just checked my end and it's now working OK.

Comment: @Prisoner: all places where it was broken yesterday can now load the image just fine. Problem resolved!